# Adding CAGradientLayer to UIImageView in UICollectionViewCell has strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, calayer

I have to add a `CAGradientLayer` to the background image of some custom `UICollectionViewCells`. I am using a Custom flow layout that display cells like this.

[RACollectionViewTripleLayout](https://github.com/ra1028/RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout)

[image: Triple Layout]

I have problems with reusability when I do scroll in the `collectionView`  and the gradient layers added to the images change their size. As you can see in this image the gradient change its size.

[image: Gradient size changed]

I also have problems with some cells, those cells add the gradient layer twice. So the shadow effect that I want to add is too dark.

I am using this code.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.gradientLayer = nil;
    self.articleImageView.image = nil;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setupGradient];
}


#pragma mark - Setup
- (void)setupGradient {
    UIColor *threeQuartersBlack = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.6];
    UIColor *halfBlack = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    UIColor *oneQuarterBlack = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGFloat gradientHeight =self.bounds.size.height/3.0;
    CGRect gradientBounds = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height-gradientHeight, self.bounds.size.width, gradientHeight);

    gradient.frame = gradientBounds;
    gradient.anchorPoint =  CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],(id)oneQuarterBlack.CGColor ,(id)halfBlack.CGColor , (id)threeQueartesBlack.CGColor, (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];

    self.gradientLayer = gradient;
    [self.articleImageView.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

I have noticed if I pop that ViewController and display it again, everything is correct.

Anyone has any idea of what should I do to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you understand your problem solved? I'm exactly your problem...

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution: remove the gradient from your UICollectionViewCell and instead add it to the UIImage you are displaying, creating a new UIImage that includes the gradient. Code to add a gradient to a UIImage is below.

```
UIImage *thumbnail = yourImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(thumbnail.size, NO, 0.0);
[thumbnail drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, thumbnail.size.width, thumbnail.size.height)];

//  Add Gradient to lower half of thumbnail
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat colors[4] = {0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.55};
CGFloat locations[2] = {0.f, 1.f};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, locations, 2);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnail.size.width/2.f, thumbnail.size.height - 40.f);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnail.size.width/2.f, thumbnail.size.height);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

UIImage *newThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

*Note: this code applies the thumbnail to the bottom 40 points of the photo. You may want to apply to bottom 25% of photo. If you use the photo in different size collection view cells, the gradient will of course scale with the photo. If you need different ratios of gradient height : photo height you will have to create multiple images. Best solution is probably to create all the different sizes of photos needed at view did load on a background thread and hook up to collection view cells as necessary - this will ensure image processing is not occurring every time a collection view cell is reused.